# How to map a flight path 3D with geographical map ? - Mathematica

Tags: plotting, geographics

currently I am trying to map a flightpath 3D in Mathematica using *height, latitude, longitude*. The actual plotting isn`t the problem. I want to have a geographical map at the bottom of the plot. So that you can see which cities are on the ground.
Code for plotting:
[image]

The only thing missing is that I get this in the xy plane(in the right scale):

```
img = GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> startPosittion]
```

[image]

This image should be on the bottom of the plot. 
Additionally it has to be scaled right so that the lat and long are right.

Thanks in advance !

Gordon

Comment: Take a look at `Texture`.

Comment: What code are you using to produce the flightpath?

Comment: It's hard to recommend anything if you don't supply your `startPosition` or the flight path itself.